# Условие совпадает, но не выполняется (Discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

У меня есть код:

```
@bot.command()
async def admin_add(ctx,member_to_admin:discord.User=None):
    if (member_to_admin == None):
        print("NO ARGS")
        return
```

Я не указываю аргумент, и по идее в консоль должно вывести **NO ARGS**, но ничего не выводит. Я проверял тип данных **member_to_admin** и выводило: **NoneType**. То есть условие выполнялось, а то что внутри него — нет.

Comment: в if уберите скобки, возможно поможет

Comment: Поставьте перед `if` печать `print(member_to_admin)` и посмотрите, что напечатает. Должно всё срабатывать, если там `None`, может у вас сама печать не работает по какой-то причине.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте не `member_to_admin == None`, а  `if not member_to_admin` или `if member_to_admin is None`

Comment: `==` в `python` сравнивает по содержанию переменной, а `is` по ссылке на объект

Comment: if member_to_admin != None:

Comment: Все эти условия должны одинаково работать, и `not` и `==` и `is`, разницы нет.